# R Select only rows equal to another row

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm struggling with a potencially silly problem, however I've yet to figure out how to solve it.

Shortly - I have a dataframe containing string and numerical columns. String columns define a key. I have to find all the keys and then for each key filter the dataframe so that the string columns are equal to the key and later do some calculations on the numerical columns. The problem is that the string column names are not fixed (it's supposed to be a generic function and a dataframe can have different number and names of string columns).

My solution so far (it works but it's painfully slow, I'm trying to make it vectorized so that it's faster):

```
only_string_columns <- df %>% select_if(is.character) # get only the string columns
only_numerical_columns <- df%>% select_if(is.numeric)
  
string_columns_names <- names(only_string_columns)
numerical_columns_names <- names(only_numerical_columns)

all_keys <- unique(only_string_columns) # get all unique keys

for(i in 1:nrow(all_keys)) {
    
    current_key <- all_keys[i, ]
    
    mask <- foreach(d=iter(only_string_columns, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %dopar% identical(unlist(d), unlist(current_key)) # create a boolean mask for rows that are equal to that specific key row
    
    selected_rows <- df[mask[,], ] # select only those that are equal to the key row
```

Previously I was trying to create a mask like this:

```
mask <- only_string_columns == current_key
OR
mask <- which(only_string_columns == current_key)
```

But they raised this error:
`‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

An example of what a dataframe could look like:

```
  country category value       date
1     USA        A     1 some_date1
2      UK        B     1 some_date2
3      UK        A     3 some_date3
4     USA        A     4 some_date4
5      UK        A     2 some_date5
6     USA        B     3 some_date6
```

Then the string columns are **country** and **category** and **value** is numerical.
Selected only string columns:

```
  country category 
1     USA        A 
2      UK        B 
3      UK        A 
4     USA        A 
5      UK        A 
6     USA        B
```

Unique keys:

```
  country category
1     USA        A
2      UK        B
3      UK        A
4     USA        B
```

So the first unique key is:

```
  country category
1     USA        A
```

After filtering, I should get this output:

```
  country category 
1     USA        A 
4     USA        A
```

Using only the filtered rows in the original df:

```
  country category value       date
1     USA        A     1 some_date1
4     USA        A     4 some_date4
```

Note: simple subsetting like (df$country == key$country) & (df$category == key$category) will not work because another dataframe that in the future could be passed as an argument could have different string columns names (so instead of a country it could be a continent, market, anything).

Edit:
Later, after the filtering is done, the pairs (date, value) are created. So I match each date with a corresponding numerical value. In that case it would be:

```
(some_date1, 1), (some_date4, 4)
```

The pairs have to be created for each key, so for the next key (UK, B) that would be:

```
(some_date2, 1)
```

Comment: Look at `group_by` function. You can use it to work on your numerical columns using the keys

Comment: What are you trying to do to the numerical columns??

Comment: @onyambu Later they'll be arranged in value pairs like (Date, value). The original dataframe also contains a date column which is not used for filtering but after the filtering is done, each numerical value will be used to create those pairs.

Comment: From the example above, include your final results in your question

Comment: @onyambu Added more information

Comment: So what happened to the keys?? You dont need them in your final output?

Comment: `df %>% filter(date == "some_date2") %>% select(date, value)` would achieve the same result

Comment: I don't really need the keys in my output, what I need are those pairs.

Comment: What type of pairs are those? Lists? Note that R does not have tuples/pairs like other languages. Or are they characters?

Comment: @onyambu R does not explicitly have value pairs like Python etc, but named lists can be used in a similar way in many cases

Comment: so do you need something like `split(df, ~country+category)` but without the character columns?

Comment: I didn't explain the numerical calculations much because they were not my primary problem. My problem was selecting only the rows of the dataframe that are equal to the key (the whole rest is already implemented and works fine).

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the `split` function;

```
split(df[3:4], df[1:2], sep='_')
$UK_A
  value       date
3     3 some_date3
5     2 some_date5

$USA_A
  value       date
1     1 some_date1
4     4 some_date4

$UK_B
  value       date
2     1 some_date2

$USA_B
  value       date
6     3 some_date6
```

I am not sure what you neeed to do after this, though note that you can work on your whole data without splitting. ie using `group_by`: